# r - How to return last value from a function

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to return the last value of a which search in a `data.frame` here is my code:

```
timepoint1 <- function(x) which(x < 1.1*min(x))[1]
timepoint2 <- function(x) which(x > 4.4*min(x))[1]

Final <- data.frame(
  Min = sapply(df,min,na.rm=1),
  Max = sapply(df,max,na.rm=1),
  T1 = sapply(df, timepoint1),
  T2 = sapply(df, timepoint2)
)
```

In the `data.frame` df there are multiple values under 1.1*min however I can't find a way to just be able to append the last value to the `data.frame` Final.

Comment: THanks wasn't too sure how it worked, but with trial and error I got it.

Answer (score 0):

since which always returns the same number of elements as its input x

you could do:

```
timepoint1 <- function(x) which(x < 1.1*min(x))[length(x)]
```